# Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object]

Tags: jquery

Working currenly on news scroller - see my live example here - **[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MrTest/dwMfv/5/)**

When I press next/prev arrow I'm getting an error log `Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object]`

Why is the problem? Where is the error in the syntax?

jQuery Code:

```
        (function($) {
    /*!  Scroller
        ---------------------------------------------*/
        $.fn.Scroller = function() {

            //Set height
            $('.scroller').each(function() {
                var height = 0;
                $(this).children('div').each(function() {

                    if (height < $(this).height()) {
                        height = $(this).height();
                    }

                });
                $(this).css("height", height + "px");

            });

            $('.scroller').each(function() {

                var NextArrow = $(this).parent().find('.next');
                var PrevArrow = $(this).parent().find('.prev');


                // Set a timeout
                var timeOut = setTimeout(nextNotice, 5000);

                // pause on hover
                $(this).hover(

                function() {
                    clearTimeout(timeOut);
                }, function() {
                    timeOut = setTimeout(nextNotice, 5000);
                });

                // Next notice function called on timeout or click
                //set a flag that use to be an oberver to listen when the fadeIn done
                var flag = true;

                function nextNotice(event) {

                    var CurrentScrollerDiv = $(this).parent().find('.scroller');

                    if (!flag) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    clearTimeout(timeOut);

                    flag = false;
                    timeOut = setTimeout(nextNotice, 5000);

                    if ($(CurrentScrollerDiv + ' div:visible').is(CurrentScrollerDiv + '  div:last-child')) {
                        $(CurrentScrollerDiv + ' div:visible').fadeOut(300);
                        $(CurrentScrollerDiv + ' div:first-child').fadeIn("slow", function() {
                            flag = true;
                        });
                    } else {
                        $(CurrentScrollerDiv + ' div:visible').fadeOut(300).next('div').fadeIn("slow", function() {
                            flag = true;
                        });
                    }
                    return false;
                }

                $(NextArrow).click(nextNotice);
                $(PrevArrow).click(function(event) {

                    var CurrentScrollerDiv = $(this).parent().find('.scroller');

                    if (flag) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    clearTimeout(timeOut);

                    flag = false;
                    timeOut = setTimeout(nextNotice, 5000);

                    if ($(CurrentScrollerDiv + ' div:visible').is(CurrentScrollerDiv + ' div:first-child')) {
                        $(CurrentScrollerDiv + ' div:visible').fadeOut(300);
                        $(CurrentScrollerDiv + ' div:last-child').fadeIn("slow", function() {
                            flag = true;
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        $(CurrentScrollerDiv + ' div:visible').fadeOut(300).prev('div').fadeIn("slow", function() {
                            flag = true;
                        });
                    }
                    return false;

                });

            });

        };

    })(jQuery);


    $(document).ready(function() {
        //Blog
        $('.itBlog > div:first-child').show();

        //Scroller
        $('.scroller').Scroller();

    });
```

Comment: That's the problem: `$(CurrentScrollerDiv + ' div:visible')`. Why do you think you can concatenate a jQuery object with a string?

Comment: On what line does the error occur?

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal - it does not say which line is it.

Comment: @Felix Kling - sorry, I'm still learning. What is wrong with this kind of usage?

Comment: @NewUser: You can find out if you perform some basic debugging with breakpoints. This should be a first step before resorting to asking here.

Comment: Well, as you could already see, the *string representation* of an object is `[object Object]`, hence the resulting string is `[object Object] div:visible`. You can do that, but it does not give you the result you want.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal - breakpoints? Like `console.log();` ?

Comment: @NewUser: http://getfirebug.com/javascript

Comment: @Felix Kling - I did not realize that this selection will create an object. I was thinking this will return string (pure text). Thanks.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal - I got my error details from console of the firebug, there was no browser alert.

Comment: @NewUser: Read the _whole_ page. It tells you what breakpoints are. Do not comment again until you have read the _whole_ page: it should take you at least ten minutes.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal - sorry - I knew what the breakpoint were - just did not knew what are they actually called. I did some breakpoints check - and once the onlick event have been fired - it was telling me the `$(this).parent().find('.scroller');` = `[]` but I was not sure that this waa the issue. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot concatenate strings to objects.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To build selectors from existing objects, use [the second parameter of `$`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/):

```
$('div:visible', CurrentScrollerDiv)
```

Or [the `find` function](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
CurrentScrollerDiv.find('div:visible');
```

`CurrentScrollerDiv` is not a string so it cannot be concatenated with a string to generate a string-based selector argument.

---

> ```
> jQuery( selector, [ context ]  )
>     jQuery( selector, [context] )    <-- you want this one, and
>     jQuery( element )                    `selector` is a string
>     jQuery( elementArray )
>     jQuery( jQuery object )
>     jQuery()
> jQuery( html, [ ownerDocument ]  )
>     jQuery( html, [ownerDocument] )
>     jQuery( html,props )
> jQuery( callback  )
>     jQuery( callback )
> ```

Comment: `CurrentScrollerDiv is not a string so it cannot be concatenated with a string to generate a string-based selector argument.` - that very useful tip. I did not realize that before. I was sure that this will return string(pure text).

Comment: Learned something new today, I always thought it would convert to string too.

Answer (score 3):

This is the problematic line:

```
if ($(CurrentScrollerDiv + ' div:visible').is(CurrentScrollerDiv + '  div:last-child')) {
```

You using string concatenation on `CurrentScrollerDiv`, which `.toString()` s the variable, which is not at all what you want. Don't try to string concatenate jQuery objects or DOM elements. Use jQuery's [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find) instead:

```
if (CurrentScrollerDiv.find('div:visible').is(CurrentScrollerDiv.find('div:last-child')) {
```

There is, however, almost certainly a more efficient way to write that `if` statement.

Answer (score 2):

Here is wrong selector:

```
var CurrentScrollerDiv = $(this).parent().find('.scroller');

$(CurrentScrollerDiv + ' div:visible')
```

fix

```
var CurrentScrollerDiv = $(this).parent().find('.scroller');
$('div:visible', CurrentScrollerDiv);
```