# Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object][rel='x']

Tags: jquery, wordpress, syntax-error

I was working on a WordPress website when I noticed that the gallery jQuery script stopped working for no apparent reason. In firebug the error I see after the page loads is this:

`Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object][rel='x']` where 'x' is a number corresponding an image in gallery. Since this is a jQuery 1.8.3. error I have no idea where to look for the real problem.

You can see the live website [here](http://www.autocollectorsgarage.com/archives/6748).

Comment: Click on an image in the gallery and the error will show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see the problem occurring because of another error occurring in your `ngg.js` file on line 30.

```
} else if (jQuery(obj).hasClass("prev")) {
    pageNumber = jQuery(obj).attr("id").substr(9);
} else if (jQuery(obj).hasClass("next")) {
    pageNumber = jQuery(obj).attr("id").substr(9);
}
```

When a next or prev button is clicked, the code is trying to find an `id` attribute on the button element clicked. When I look at the HTML they have no `id`.

Try replacing the above with this:

```
} else if (jQuery(obj).hasClass("prev")) {
    pageNumber--;
} else if (jQuery(obj).hasClass("next")) {
    pageNumber++;
}
```

Comment: I suspect that the images should be cycled, so it's the same code being executed on a timer that appears in the Console soon after the page loads.

Comment: I made the modifications in `ngg.js` but it doesn't solve anything. When you click on an image the error shows up again and again. The ngg.js is part of another plugin which I disabled now to make sure there are no conflicts.

Comment: Ahh ok. I just checked. Let me take a look.

Comment: Have you removed the `ngg.js` file? Take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469925/uncaught-syntax-error-unrecognized-expression-object-object. They had a similar problem and it was due to improperly building selectors. I'd also make sure the loopSlider plugin is compatible with the version of jQuery that you're using.

Comment: Thanks for helping! You we're right about the loopSlider version. It was developed for jQuery 1.3.2 and when I updated wordpress, jQuery changed to 1.8.2. I made the switch and now everything works.